# How can I open/move a browser window left of the main screen?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, multiscreen

I am creating a private web app for somebody using a three screen layout.

I would like to be able to open certain links in a new window on the left screen and others in a new window on the right screen (with the centre one as the main screen).

This can be accomplished rather easily in Firefox (as long as the main screen isn't massively larger than the others) by opening the new window to the left or right of the main screen and maximizing the window.

```
function openRight()
{
    var rightWindow = window.open(myURL,'TestRight','left='+window.screen.width+',top=0,fullscreen=yes');
    rightWindow.focus();
}
function openLeft()
{
    var leftWindow = window.open(myURL,'TestLeft','left='+(-window.screen.width)+',top=0,fullscreen=yes');
    leftWindow.focus();
}
```

IE and Chrome, however, do not allow negative values for coordinates, preventing the left screen window from opening on the correct screen.

Does anybody know of a way to do this in any browser other than Firefox (even ones I haven't listed)?

Answer (score 0):

As much as it pains me to suggest, because I suggest against doing a design like you describe is to look into [frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) or [inline frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Frames allow you to load three separate documents in each panel that don't disturb each other when the user navigates in one of them.

The only downside to frames is that the browsers back/forward buttons can cause a headache for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am intentionally wanting this sort of design (mostly to see if it is possible).  I would certainly never use this for a public website.

Comment: @Krylose, then I apologize for my answer. It's not very helpful to you, but I'll leave it up in case somebody else comes to this question and they don't know about frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.moveTo(x,y) after you have opened the window. IE allows negative value for X on the moveTo function. I have not checked chrome.

Comment: It does not do this on my computer.
I am using IE9.